# Ошибка C2864 при работе с OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

Кто сталкивался с данной проблемой при работе с OpenCV? Язык С++, работаю в VS2013.

Ошибка  1   error C2864: "cv::sfinae::has_parenthesis_operator::value": статический элемент данных с инициализатором внутри класса должен иметь неизменяемый целочисленный тип const c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\opencv2\core\cvstd_wrapper.hpp 52  1   Second_test

Вот собственно и весь код:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/types_c.h>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core_c.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Может просто студия слишком старая?

Comment: Вы собирали библиотеки из исходников OpenCV или взяли уже собранные библиотеки?  Далее, у Вас проходит канонический тест с единственным #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp" ?

Comment: @Александр Муксимов: Если `cvstd_wrapper.hpp` является интерфейсным заголовочным файлом, то не имеет никакого значения, собрана ли уже библиотека или нет.

Comment: @AnT я задал два разных вопроса. К сожалению в OpenCV бывают косяки, когда все работает в debug, но не работает в release и когда перемешиваются header от разных версий, и когда OpenCV приходиться собирать заново. Ваш глубокий анализ в ответе очень четко подтверждает, что новая версия OpenCV - новый геморрой :). От меня "+"

Answer (score 1):

Объявление этой строке в `cvstd_wrapper.hpp` [имеет вид](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp#L52)

```
static CV_CONSTEXPR bool value = type::value;
```

Такое объявление будет корректным в С++ только если `CV_CONSTEXPR` заменяется на `constexpr` или на `const` (или на `inline`, но здесь подразумевается константность).

Определение макроса в `cvdef.h` [имеет вид](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h#L688)

```
#ifndef CV_CONSTEXPR
#  if __cplusplus >= 201103L || (defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1900/*MSVS 2015*/)
#    define CV_CONSTEXPR constexpr
#  endif
#endif
#ifndef CV_CONSTEXPR
#  define CV_CONSTEXPR
#endif
```

То есть по какой-то причине они не определяют `CV_CONSTEXPR` как `const` тогда, когда не могут определить его как `constexpr`. Это странно.

История изменений показывает такое [22 дня назад](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/8518d078d75a1edbf7046c584f2429d5b1d24aed)

```
  #ifndef CV_CONSTEXPR
- #  define CV_CONSTEXPR const
+ #  define CV_CONSTEXPR
  #endif
```

То есть `const` там таки был, но некто "alalek" выкосил этот `const` нафиг. Скорее всего он исправлял что-то другое, но в результате "убил" это место в `cvstd_wrapper.hpp`. К тому же, судя по тому, что это fallback, это "перетягивание каната" длится уже некоторое время. Типичный опенсорсовский бардак.

Как видно по комментарию к этому коммиту, в других местах кода у них используются объявления вида

```
static CV_CONSTEXPR const int var = ...;
```

с явным `const`. Но раз "alalek" сделал это исправление, то тогда нужно приводить к этому виду - с явным `const` - все такие места, включая `cvstd_wrapper.hpp` тоже.

Либо ждите пока исправят этот косяк, либо берите более новую версию VS и работайте в режиме C++11 или выше.